# Converting a DataFrame column of characters to integer representation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ord

I have a dataframe with a column of characters that I want to convert to integers. Some of the characters are multichar e.g. '\b'. Running apply using ord results in a TypeError.

I tried using ord() for conversion and it works fine run by itself, but throws a TypeError when I try to use it on the DataFrame:

```
ft_x['keyCode'].apply(lambda row : ord(row))

TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

The TypeError is thrown when the character '\b' is reached.

Just doing this however works as expected:

```
x = '\b'
ord(x)

8
```

What am I missing here?

When run on the dataframe elements ord() is interpreting characters like '\b' as strings, instead of what they are - unicode representations of characters - backspace in the case of '\b'.

For reference I'm working on this dataset:
https://ieee-dataport.org/open-access/emosurv-typing-biometric-keystroke-dynamics-dataset-emotion-labels-created-using
using the FixedTextTypingDataset.csv
I need the keyCode column as Integers.

```
print(ft_x.loc[ft_x['keyCode'].str.len() > 1, 'keyCode'].head(5))
```

```
33        \b
34    \u0010
35    \u0010
36    \u0010
37    \u0010
Name: keyCode, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a list inside `apply` to transform each character of the string:

```
ft_x['ord'] = (ft_x['keyCode'].str.encode('utf-8')
                              .str.decode('unicode-escape')
                              .map(ord))

# Output
  keyCode  ord
0       a   97
1      \b    8
2  \u0030   48
```

Comment: That's unfortunately not what I'm looking for. The elements in the column are all valid characters like '\b' that should be interpreted by ord() as 8 - when applied to elements in the dataframe however a TypeError is thrown instead of the expected result.

Comment: @Tomat0. I updated my answer. Can you check it please? I think I got it :-)

Comment: Still the same TypeError getting thrown :(

TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `print(ft_x.loc[ft_x['keyCode'].str.len() > 1, 'keyCode'].head(5))`

Answer (score 0):

Converting the multi-character strings to bytes and then back to integers works.

```
def char_to_int(char):
    #ignore NaNs
    if type(char) == float:
      pass
    elif len(char) == 1:
        return int(ord(char))
    else:
        return int(int.from_bytes(char.encode(), byteorder='big'))

ft_x['keyCode'] = ft_x['keyCode'].apply(char_to_int)
```